# Valor vue-the-mask formatação condicional

Tags: html, vue.js

Eu estou tentando colocar uma máscara - vue-the-mask

```
<the-mask 
    id="input1" 
    v-model="ch_anual" 
    type="text" 
    :mask="['###:##', '#.###:##']" 
/>
```

Mas, está pegando apenas a segunda máscara
se eu coloco `###.###.###-##`, `##.###.###/####-##` funciona

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luissouza/4vdsepun/

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque você tem duas mascaras agindo no mesmo segmento, que seria do 5 digito, ou seja na primeira mascara você tem a mascara agindo no 5 caractere aplicando ###-## e ao mesmo tempo você tem a outra mascara agindo aplicando #.###-#

Pode parecer confuso mas esse componente ele age nos caracteres de controle nesse caso 2 dois agindo no 5 caractere.